# Click off to close?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this code that creates a side menu.

https://jsfiddle.net/oak22424/xy1a4hqe/

And this code which closes the side menu.

```js
function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
}
```

It is created so when you click the "×" in the side menu, it will close the side pane. How can I add to this the ability to execute the same JavaScript function (called closenav) when you click anywhere but the menu area?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can wrap the content in a "container" and then assign an event listener ('click')

```js
let doc = document.getElementById('container');
doc.addEventListener('click', () => closeNav());

function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  transition: background-color .5s;
}

.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

#main {
  transition: margin-left .5s;
  padding: 16px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {
    padding-top: 15px;
  }
  .sidenav a {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>
<div id="main">
  <div id="container">
    <h2>Sidenav Push Example</h2>
    <p>Click on the element below to open the side navigation menu, and push this content to the right. Notice that we add a black see-through background-color to body when the sidenav is opened.</p>

  </div>
  <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create `backdrop` that spans the whole screen, when the `sidenav` is open, hide it when `sidenav` is closed, then listen to click events on it.

So it would be something like this:

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
  document.getElementById("backdrop").style.display = 'block'

}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
  document.getElementById("backdrop").style.display = 'none'

}

window.onclick = (event) => {
  let backDrop = document.getElementById('backdrop');


  if (event.target == backDrop) {
    closeNav();
  }

}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  transition: background-color .5s;
}

.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

#backdrop {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

#main {
  transition: margin-left .5s;
  padding: 16px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {
    padding-top: 15px;
  }
  .sidenav a {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>

<body>

  <div id="backdrop">

  </div>
  <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Services</a>
    <a href="#">Clients</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
  </div>

  <div id="main">
    <h2>Sidenav Push Example</h2>
    <p>Click on the element below to open the side navigation menu, and push this content to the right. Notice that we add a black see-through background-color to body when the sidenav is opened.</p>
    <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>
  </div>



</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a "`click`" event listener to the part of the document that closes the side menu when the target of the event is neither the open button nor contained within the side menu itself.

```js
document.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    if (e.target.id !== "openBtn" && !document.getElementById("mySidenav").contains(e.target)) {
    //Note that I added an ID to the open button
    closeNav();
  }
})
```

Live Example:

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
}

document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (e.target.id !== 'openBtn' && !document.getElementById("mySidenav").contains(e.target)) {
    closeNav();
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  transition: background-color .5s;
}

.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

#main {
  transition: margin-left .5s;
  padding: 16px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {
    padding-top: 15px;
  }
  .sidenav a {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>
<div id="main">
  <h2>Sidenav Push Example</h2>
  <p>Click on the element below to open the side navigation menu, and push this content to the right. Notice that we add a black see-through background-color to body when the sidenav is opened.</p>
  <span id="openBtn" style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a mouse click listener and if the menu is showing and the mouse-x position is greater than the sidebar's rightmost point (dynamically calculated by div position, clientX, and width) then it calls the same javascript function you've already written to close.

Answer (score 0):

Just put this code into your JavaScript, and I have the same sidebar on my website too, lol. w3Schools squad.

```
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == mysidenav) {
    mysidenav.style.display = "none"; // Choose Either display:none; or Closenav()
    closenav(); // Choose Either CloseNav() or display:none; I recommend closenav()
  }
}
```